# VSCode debug Typescript app

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an app written in TypeScript that uses `import` statements.  I've followed the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/node-debugging) to enable debugging in VSCode.  VSCode build command is creating output .js and .map files in out-tsc.  However when I try to debug, I get the error below:

```
Debugger attached.
/Users/integrityinspired/Documents/Dev/basilisk-island/dist/out-tsc/server/src/app.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { initQueues } from '../../shared/firebase-app';
                                                            ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:590:10)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect... 

{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-w", "-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "isWatching": true,
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch"
}
```

Of note is that the import of the type is dropped from the js, and it's the import of a function that fails.

app.ts

```
import { HandlerDef } from '../../shared/handler/handler-def';
import { initQueues } from '../../shared/firebase-app';

const handlers: HandlerDef[] = [
];
initQueues('app', handlers);
```

app.js (compiled by VSCode)

```
import { initQueues } from '../../shared/firebase-app';
const handlers = [];
initQueues('app', handlers);
//# sourceMappingURL=/Users/integrityinspired/Documents/Dev/basilisk-island/server/src/app.js.map
```

firebase-app.ts

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import * as Queue from 'firebase-queue';
import { HandlerDef } from './handler/handler-def';
import { createQueue } from './queue-wrapper';

export function initQueues(queue: string, handlers: HandlerDef[]): void {
    const config = firebaseConfig();
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    let envSuffix: string = '';
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        console.log('Running in dev mode');
        envSuffix = '-dev';
    }
    const ref = firebase.database().ref(`/queue${envSuffix}/${queue}`);
    handlers.forEach(def => {
        createQueue(ref, def);
    });
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "client",
    "node_modules",
    "public",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for node debugging
    // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
    // For further information visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Server",
            "type": "node2",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/dist/out-tsc/server/src/app.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "outFiles": [],
            "sourceMaps": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "type": "node2",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9229,
            "outFiles": [],
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tsconfig.json` I needed to change `"module": "es6",` to `"module": "commonjs"`.